# Unexpected NameError from input()

Tags: python

I was just doing some practice in python I tried to print an input vairable but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mva1.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input("what is your name?")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Francis' is not defined
```

Here's my code:

```
name = input("what is your name?")
if name is "Francis":
    print "Welcome"
```

I also did this:

```
name = input("what is your name?")
print name
```

and on running it, I typed my name and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/frankscute's/Practices/mva1.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input("what is your name?")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Francis' is not defined
```

I'm using Python 2.7 on PyCharm IDE

Comment: you are using python 2.7 instead of input, user raw_input

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 uses `raw_input` not `input`. Use Python 3.2 for `input` for taking a user input. (in this case)

```
name = raw_input("what is your name?")
if name is "Francis":
    print "Welcome"# your code goes here
```

Comment: Python 2.7 uses `input` too, just differently.

Comment: Yes I agree but in this case we just use raw_input

Comment: Thanks for the tip